# IF Statement on Button to make it complete and "uncomplete" based on user action / click

Tags: functions, customization

I am just working on an LMS and there is a php if statement, that from as much as i can read, says if the button is clicked return this state e.g. set the button and lesson as Completed (default state is Complete):

```
<?php if (!empty($completed_label)): ?>
        <div <?php echo apply_filters('lms_navigation_complete_atts', '', $item_id); ?>
                class="<?php echo apply_filters('lms_navigation_complete_class', 'lms-lesson_navigation_complete', $item_id); ?>">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default lms_complete_lesson <?php echo esc_attr($completed); ?>"
               data-course="<?php echo intval($post_id) ?>"
               data-lesson="<?php echo intval($item_id); ?>">
                <span><?php echo sanitize_text_field($completed_label); ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

From my end i can kind of read whats happening, however, what iv tried to do is add an else statement (is that right?) to say else, if the parameter isnt !empty then revert it back to Complete.

I literally duplicated the whole bit and tried to edit it.

That doesnt work.

The idea is to allow users to toggle lessons between Complete / Completed.

Here is another attempt at making the button revert:

```
 <?php if (isset($completed_label)): ?>
        <div <?php echo apply_filters('lms_navigation_complete_atts', '', $item_id); ?>
                class="<?php echo apply_filters('lms_navigation_complete_class', 'lms-lesson_navigation_complete', $item_id); ?>">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default lms_complete_lesson <?php echo esc_html__('Complete', 'lms-learning-management-system'); ?>"
               data-course="<?php echo intval($post_id) ?>"
               data-lesson="<?php echo intval($item_id); ?>">
                <span><?php echo esc_html__('Complete', 'lms-learning-management-system'); ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, is the Completed label set meaning is it not empty, if it is, make it clickable, if its clickable revert it back.

I thought of this, due to what i feel is another key part part which controls it:

```
  $completed = (LMS_Lesson::is_lesson_completed('', $post_id, $item_id)) ? 'completed' : 'uncompleted';
    $completed_label = (!empty($completed)) ? esc_html__('Complete', 'lms-learning-management-system') : esc_html__('Completed', 'lms-learning-management-system');
```

So in this code higher up in the document i feel this sets the Complete by default and then the Completed if the element isnt empty, or when users click.